# Stored Procedure Error: an exception occurred while executing a transact-sql statement or batch , invalid object name 'sys.all_objects'

Tags: stored-procedures, ssms

Am trying to expand the Store Procedure in SQL Server 2012 x64 but there is a error prompts. Any Help? Thank you.

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Invalid object name 'sys.all_objects'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.3128&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=208&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

[image]

Comment: Please dont use images for text information.  How is anyone going to try and search the text for you?  If you cant be bothered to type them in, others won't either.

Comment: Hi Rohit, error is already displayed on the Title, hope you can help me out with it. Thanks.

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: Hi J.D, were using SQL Server 2012 x64 STD.

Comment: Can you select "manually" from the mentioned view? (`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM sys.all_objects`)

Comment: Hi Yano, same error occur

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.all_objects'.